# How do I parse {"access_token":"Abcd45689012031"}

Tags: perl

How do I parse this. Input ={"access_token":"Abcd45689012031"} and out put = "Abcd45689012031"

Answer (score 1):

That looks like JSON. Hence use a [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) parser:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my $json = JSON->new;
my $object = $json->decode('{"access_token":"Abcd45689012031"}')
    or die "JSON\n";

print $object->{access_token}, "\n";

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
Abcd45689012031
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON), [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS), or even [Cpanel::JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/Cpanel::JSON::XS) to parse JSON:

```
use JSON::XS qw{ decode_json };

my $input = '{"access_token":"Abcd45689012031"}';
my $json  = decode_json($input);
my $token = $json->{access_token};
```